# Converting from RGB to HSL with Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rgb, hsl

I'm quite new to objective c but have been programming for a while. I started creating a function that would convert from RGB to HSL and back again but I get a feeling it is way too long and headed in the wrong direction. Does anyone know of a simple way to perform this conversion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NSColor is missing in iPhone SDK. You can use this utility to convert from RGB to HSL space and back:

https://github.com/alessani/ColorConverter

Answer (score 4):

You can use `NSColor`, I think.

```
CGFloat r, g, b, a, h, s, b, a2;
NSColor *c = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:a];
[c getHue:&h saturation:&s brightness:&b alpha:&a2];
```

On second thought, I don't know if `NSColor` is available in the iPhone frameworks or not - isn't there a `UIColor`?  Anyway I'll leave this answer in case someone searching for an OS X solution ends up here.

Comment: +1, though HSL isn't quite the same as HSB/HSV. The H and S should be the same, though.

Comment: @Wevah, wikipedia says it's not very standardized, and that any of the names can go with any of the models.  I'm not enough of an expert to know the subtleties though.

Comment: Well, they're *sort* of standard. Almost. Mostly it's just unfortunate that the built-in stuff doesn't handle HSL(ightness). :/ And if he really does want HSV/HSB, then your answer is perfect!

Comment: There is indeed a UIColor! (I missed the `iphone` tag, too.)

Comment: Thanks Carl, I tried using UIColor which got me a little closer but I get the error 'UIColor may not respond to -getHue:saturation:brightness:alpha'

Comment: The HUE is the only similar value in HSB and HSL. The S (Saturation) are not calculated the same.

Comment: -getHue:saturation:brightness:alpha is from available starting with iOS5

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I'm using:

```
 static void RVNColorRGBtoHSL(CGFloat red, CGFloat green, CGFloat blue, CGFloat *hue, CGFloat *saturation, CGFloat *lightness)
{
    CGFloat r = red / 255.0f;
    CGFloat g = green / 255.0f;
    CGFloat b = blue / 255.0f;

    CGFloat max = MAX(r, g);
    max = MAX(max, b);
    CGFloat min = MIN(r, g);
    min = MIN(min, b);

    CGFloat h;
    CGFloat s;
    CGFloat l = (max + min) / 2.0f;

    if (max == min) {
        h = 0.0f;
        s = 0.0f;
    }

    else {
        CGFloat d = max - min;
        s = l > 0.5f ? d / (2.0f - max - min) : d / (max + min);

        if (max == r) {
            h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6.0f : 0.0f);
        }

        else if (max == g) {
            h = (b - r) / d + 2.0f;
        }

        else if (max == b) {
            h = (r - g) / d + 4.0f;
        }

        h /= 6.0f;
    }

    if (hue) {
        *hue = roundf(h * 255.0f);
    }

    if (saturation) {
        *saturation = roundf(s * 255.0f);
    }

    if (lightness) {
        *lightness = roundf(l * 255.0f);
    }
}
```

And here's how to call it:

```
CGFloat h, s, l;
RVNColorRGBtoHSL(r, g, b,
                 &h, &s, &l);
```

Comment: Thanks! Runs much more quickly than using `NSColor`.

Comment: Update: This function actually returns different hue values than I think it should. When I use it to select different hue ranges from a color wheel, it jumps around. In contrast, the following solution rotates around the color wheel as I'd expect: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6930407/1976584

Answer (score 0):

You can add the UIColor-HSVAdditions.h/.m category to your app to add a set of operations to UIColor for working with hue, saturation and value.  See http://bravobug.com/news/?p=448 and 
this 
[ArsTechnica](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/02/iphone-development-accessing-uicolor-components.ars) article  also.