# Return lighter color from SKColor using HSL lightness factor

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uicolor

I have an iOS SKColor, that I want to convert to a lighter shade (that is opaque with no opacity/no transparency), therefore I would like to implement a function using the HSL lightness, that returns an SKColor. ie. inside the function, convert the original SKColor to the HSL equivalent, then apply a value to the HSL lightness to get a lighter color shade, then convert this HSL color back to an SKColor that I can use.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598043/get-slightly-lighter-and-darker-color-from-uicolor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xcode 14.3 • Swift 5.8

```
extension UIColor {

    convenience init(
        hue: CGFloat,
        saturation: CGFloat,
        lightness: CGFloat,
        alpha: CGFloat = 1
    )  {
        let offset = saturation * (lightness < 0.5 ? lightness : 1 - lightness)
        let brightness = lightness + offset
        let saturation = lightness > 0 ? 2 * offset / brightness : 0
        self.init(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: brightness, alpha: alpha)
    }

    var hsl: (
        hue: CGFloat,
        saturation: CGFloat,
        lightness: CGFloat,
        alpha: CGFloat
    )? {
        var (red, green, blue, alpha, hue): (CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat) = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        guard
            getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha),
            getHue(&hue, saturation: nil, brightness: nil, alpha: nil)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        let upper = max(red, green, blue)
        let lower = min(red, green, blue)
        let range = upper - lower
        let lightness = (upper + lower) / 2
        let saturation = range == 0 ? 0 : range / (lightness < 0.5 ? lightness * 2 : 2 - lightness * 2)
        return (hue, saturation, lightness, alpha)
    }

    func getHSL(_ hue: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGFloat>?, saturation: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGFloat>?, lightness: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGFloat>?, alpha: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGFloat>?) -> Bool {
        guard let hsl else { return false }
        hue?.pointee = hsl.hue
        saturation?.pointee = hsl.saturation
        lightness?.pointee = hsl.lightness
        alpha?.pointee = hsl.alpha
        return true
    }
}
```

---

```
extension UIColor {

    var lighter: UIColor? { adding(lightness: 0.1) }
    var darker: UIColor? { adding(lightness: -0.1) }

    func adding(lightness value: CGFloat) -> UIColor? {
        guard let hsl else { return nil }
        return UIColor(
            hue: hsl.hue,
            saturation: hsl.saturation,
            lightness: min(max(hsl.lightness + value, 0),1),
            alpha: hsl.alpha
        )
    }

    func applying(lightness value: CGFloat) -> UIColor? {
        guard let hsl else { return nil }
        return UIColor(
            hue: hsl.hue,
            saturation: hsl.saturation,
            lightness: value,
            alpha: hsl.alpha
        )
    }
}
```

---

```
let purple = UIColor(red: 160/255, green: 118/255, blue: 200/255, alpha: 1)
let lighter = purple.lighter
```

Answer (score 0):

As the official [SKColor](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SpriteKitFunctionReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/SKColor) doc says, on iOS, a `SKColor` is just a `UIColor`. Hence:

```
UIColor *uicolor = (UIColor *)skcolor;
CGFloat h, s, b, a; // lightness is called 'brightness' 
[uicolor getHue:&h saturation:&s brightness:&b alpha:&a];

// (play with your brightness value here)

SKColor *skcolor2 = (SKColor *)[UIColor colorWithHue:h saturation:s brightness:b alpha:a];
```

Comment: HSL is not the same color space as HSB.

Comment: Yep sorry. So you could use the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017553/converting-from-rgb-to-hsl-with-objective-c to convert from RGB to HSL, and back.

Comment: Hi, I'll try the answer suggested by onekiloparsec - but because I am quite new to iOS, I am using Swift rather than ObjectiveC - do you know what the equivalent code is, in Swift?