# How to make UIColor "softer"

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

Often look at other applications that can make the color different but close to the color. It's like the two colors of the appendix.

How can UIColor be achieved?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add transparency

Comment: Google "color families" for one approach. Your example might just be an decreased `alpha` value but it's hard to tell from here.

Comment: Did you try the `alpha` parameter? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcolor/1456637-alpha

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/30012117/2303865

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution than lowering the alpha (which may cause other things behind it to appear) is to lower the color's saturation.

Here's a `UIColor` extension that gets the HSB of a color, lowers the saturation, and returns the new color with the same alpha:

```
extension UIColor {
    func softer() -> UIColor {
        var h: CGFloat = 0
        var s: CGFloat = 0
        var b: CGFloat = 0
        var a: CGFloat = 0
        if self.getHue(&h, saturation: &s, brightness: &b, alpha: &a) {
            // Change the 0.5 to suit your needs
            return UIColor(hue: h, saturation: s * 0.5, brightness: b, alpha: a)
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}

// Examples:    
let orange = UIColor.orange
let softOrange = orange.softer()
let brown = UIColor(red: 0.4392, green: 0.2510, blue: 0.1882, alpha: 1.0)
let softBrown = brown.softer()
```

Comment: I think that it would be better to use hue saturation lightness for that

Comment: @LeoDabus `UIColor` only has APIs for HSB, not HSL. But yes, messing with the lightness or saturation are some of the various ways to adjust the color.

Answer (score 1):

```
    let color = UIColor.red                       //Your uicolor
    let softColor = color.withAlphaComponent(0.5) //0<->1.0
```